Duplicated Headings in SharePoint List Forms
Recently, while immersed in the task of formatting the form body within the Site Pages library, my objective was to introduce structured headings to categorize the various fields. Leveraging JSON, the following structure was employed:
{
    "sections": [
        {
            "displayname": "Main info",
            "fields": [
                "Name",
                "Title"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Other info",
            "fields": []
        }
    ]
}

Initially, the integration of headings into the form seemed successful, providing clarity and organization for users navigating through the fields.

However, a perplexing anomaly emerged when inspecting the details pane within the Site Pages list. While the headings were appropriately displayed, an unexpected duplication occurred within the standard SharePoint Scheduling section.

Do you know how to solve this?
Wrap up
Goal: categorize details (fields) of a list item in Site Pages using headers.
Issue: headers are repeated in the standard Scheduling section.
Issue is marked as solved: the issue is solved when the headers are visible in the details pane, but not in de Scheduling section.
